# DNS - Firebase connect to Namecheap still says Needs setup?

Tags: firebase, dns, hosting, firebase-hosting, namecheap

Ok, it has been less than 24 hrs but more than 10, and I find it odd that I am still getting a status of Needs setup in Firebase just trying to redirect to a custom domain, bought with Namecheap. I don't know what Im doing wrong but I still get the "insecure connection" error trying to access my site.

Here are the records specified in Firebase to be added to my Namecheap records:

[image]

Namecheap is in accordance:

[image]

I used @ for the same host as specified by Namecheap - is something wrong? How long should this take if not?

Comment: Did the answer below solve your issue? Any progress on this?

Answer (score 57):

You need to change the `CNAME` record to your firebase app URL:
`example-app.firebaseapp.com.` (Make sure to include the dot at the end) and you should also change the `TTL` on both `A records` to Automatic.
Then, delete the `URL Redirect` record.
That should fix your problem. I'd wait up to an hour after these changes for the changes to take effect.

[This is what my namecheap DNS setup looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ILGJ.png)
I added the `www` A records because I have a redirect in my Firebase console, but you don't need those.

Comment: I'm not the OP but I had the same problem and this answer solved it perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: This worked for me. I had my first domain working, but tried to add a redirect domain, which was the same domain prefixed with www. It was stuck for a day with the status of "needs setup" until I applied the exact same configuration you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: Note: Our default TTL is 30 minutes. You can select it from the drop-down or just leave it "Automatic". ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252041/dns-firebase-connect-to-namecheap-still-says-needs-setup?rq=1  So  TTL is 30 minutes needed for godaddy ?

Comment: by editing my CNAME to default URL provided by firebase solved my issue

Comment: WORKS! Life Saviour. Thank you Devin

Answer (score 21):

Expanding on Devin's answer which helped immensely... Here are the steps that worked for me.

1. Go to the Firebase console and click 'connect domain', and add your domain
2. Remove all DNS records in Namecheap
3. Add the TXT record that Google/Firebase suggests
4. Go back to the Firebase console and click 'connect domain'
5. Verify the domain ownership
6. Add in the A records that Google/Firebase suggests
7. Add a CNAME record pointing to the default Firebase URL, and any A records that Google/Firebase suggests for a site redirect, if you have one.

Comment: thank you! Just adding to above point 7, add "www" in the "Host" field (Godaddy) and firebase URL in "Point to"  field.

Comment: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9137747?hl=en 'For your custom domain, if your DNS records have A records or CNAME records that point to other providers, Firebase is unable to provision an SSL certificate.' so CNAME should be default Firebase URL right?

Answer (score 11):

First delete all existing default records. Then you only need 5 records. No CNAME records are required.

[image: DNS records for Firebase custom domains]

Subdomains are just as simple. Just replace `www` with whatever you want (e.g. admin).
[image: DNS records for Firebase custom subdomain]

Add the custom subdomain under Firebase hosting and the SSL certificate will be automatically provisioned if you wait about 5-10mins.

**PS** : Take a moment to appreciate that - with Firebase you will never have to to buy, sign and install SSL certs again. Even multi-domain, wildcard SSL certs are automatically taken care of.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as stated on firebase docs

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain#dns-records-namecheap

[image]

Comment: Saved the day! This is an underrated answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I simply accidentally put "*" instead of "@" as the host. Otherwise, my DNS settings look just like Fakeer's, also on namecheap. Worked like a charm.