# Firebase CDN with Namecheap DNS: Site won't load with "www" prefix

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, namecheap

I've been learning how to use Firebase hosting to host Angular apps, but I've been struggling with this DNS issue for over a week now and have had no luck solving it. I have an simple Angular(v7) web app hosted on the Firebase CDN. When I navigate to my site without the "www" prefix (https://howmuchhouse.org/) it loads just fine, but when I add the prefix "WWW" (https://www.howmuchhouse.org/) I get the following error:

> Site Not Found
> Why am I seeing this?
> There are a few potential reasons:
>
> You haven't deployed an app yet.
> You may have deployed an empty directory.
> This is a custom domain, but we haven't finished setting it up yet.

**This is my Namecheap setup**
[image]

**And on firebase hosting it shows as "connected"**
[image]

I've gone over all the Firebase and NameCheap documentation and come up empty handed. This is my first time ever hosting an app so I may be not using the right terminology in my searches. I also looked at a few StackOverflow posts regarding similar issues like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53429442/domain-with-www-prefix-not-working-on-firebase-hosting) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252041/dns-firebase-connect-to-namecheap-still-says-needs-setup). Any help or ideas would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your screenshot shows that you have `howmuchhouse.org` connected to your Firebase app. You also need to [connect](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain#set_up_your_domain_for) `www.howmuchhouse.org` from within the Firebase console and have it redirect to the non-www version. The Firebase config should look like this:

[image]

Comment: You should also not have the `CNAME` for `www`. The two `A` records for `www` are enough.

Comment: It worked! I am embarrassed I didn't think of that. Thank you very much Abraham!