# How to Map Godaddy Domain with FIrebase Hosted Application

Tags: firebase, url, hosting, firebase-hosting

[Firebase Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueh6g.png)[Godaddy DNS ControlPannel Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUdy5.png)
I am trying to set a domain name I purchased from godaddy for an application hosted in Firebase with its custom Domain.

Following I tried But this didn't helped me 
[Firebase hosting not validating TXT record in GoDaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51024319/firebase-hosting-not-validating-txt-record-in-godaddy)

And tried the godaddy DNS Config without 'www.' and also tried the @ but its not allowing to add @  and submit it in godaddy.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Comment: Step by step solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427383/how-can-i-verify-my-custom-domain-on-firebase-using-godaddy/60431369#60431369

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Godaddy allows @ as host name in txt record. you should enter @ in hostname and google-site verification code in txt value. or you can check https://in.godaddy.com/help/add-a-txt-record-19232 or you can call in customer care of godaddy and ask them to add this record in DNS in technical help. They will do

Comment: Hi Ketan. Thanks for your help. Actually It helped. Is it mandatory to have SSL certificate?

Comment: Getting Following Error -> 
Can’t connect securely to this page
This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps happening, try contacting the website’s owner.

Comment: not mandatory SSL I guess. where you getting this error exactly? while using firebase syntax or while loading your site in browser?

Comment: Thanks Ketan for helping me. It is fixed. It takes a bit of time to map and provide SSL. Firebase Provides that Automatically.

Comment: @AnindyoBose can you share your godaddy DNS management config screenshot? with ref to some old post *CNAME www mysitesample.firebaseapp.com 1 Hour* adding Cname is not needed? like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ILGJ.png have you added cname ? (got it from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252041/dns-firebase-connect-to-namecheap-still-says-needs-setup/48936896)

Comment: The `@` is quite important to verify.

Comment: Simple step by step solution with screenshots https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427383/how-can-i-verify-my-custom-domain-on-firebase-using-godaddy/60431369#60431369

Answer (score 0):

The terminology between google site verification and the GoDaddy DNS records are slightly confusing, they use different words though they mean the same. Basically you need TXT and CNAME records to be updated in DNS provider or domain hosting provider records, here in GoDaddy DNS records.

[image]

Updating TXT record alone works, CNAME label and destination update as well important, especially when you are editing the records post initial authentication.